# GRUB booting only when the drive is explicitly selected

Tags: debian, boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

This is my first time having a fancy UEFI PC. I partitioned all my drives in GPT using *gdisk*.

1. installed Windows 10
2. installing Debian
3. at the end of the installation a dialogue box warned me that many EFI implementations are buggy and had I wanted to install GRUB on a removable media (didn't tell what that media was). I clicked "yes"
4. GRUB didn't detect Windows 10
5. rebooted my PC
6. no GRUB. booted straight to Windows 10.

When I picked the drive explicitly from the boot menu (pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>):

[image]

it did boot into Debian, though I have to do this at every boot.
is there a way to make GRUB detect Windows 10 and be the default bootloader like back in the good old days of MBR?

Answer (score 4):

As for GRUB detecting Windows, no. GRUB works differently in a UEFI setup, and will only be used to boot Debian.

To be more specific, in an UEFI system a *boot manager* displays an initial menu of *boot loaders*; such as GRUB, systemd-boot, an actual Linux kernel, Windows, Mac OSX...

So to create a setup similar to the old MBR days, you can install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), which is a *boot manager*. The benefit to rEFInd is that you don't have to mess around with the UEFI firmware to select which *boot loader* to use, which is effectively what you're doing right now. Instead, rEFInd displays whatever *boot loaders* you have installed and lets you choose one.

To set it up, boot up Debian and then run `apt-get install refind`. You'll be prompted with a red text-based dialog whether to install it or not (which means whether to copy some files to /boot/EFI). Choose *yes* to install it.

When you reboot you should see a graphical menu to choose Windows or Debian.

Note: You may see two options for Debian. One for the Linux kernel itself and one for GRUB. Choose GRUB.

Comment: i reinstalled the system after proprietary nvidia drivers crashed it. i again chose 'yes' to install GRUB to EFI removable path: https://vgy.me/Khvdv4.jpg this time around GRUB detected windows boot loader and now i can choose it from the GRUB menu! how this came to be?!